# Why do installers and some applications appear as external disks on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I've enabled the option to show external disks on my desktop on my Mac. Why do installers like "Adobe Flash Player Installer" and programs like "Steam" appear on the desktop after enabling this option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do software .dmg files mount or work in OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/34910/how-do-software-dmg-files-mount-or-work-in-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you download DMG files which are virtual Disk Images. When you open the DMG file OSX mount it as it would do for any other removable disk such as CD or USB stick.